# GoogleMap SDK iOS 1.6 Error Log

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I just updated GoogleMap SDK Framework for my app, from v1.5 to v1.6. I downloaded the SDK from Google Developer website.

Everything was fine. I can compile and build successfully. But right after my app start and display the map, I found some logs that I believe this came from GoogleMap SDK

Error: : Cannot find image GMSSprites-0_retina
Error: : Image data can't be NULL.
Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.6.0.6204

The app itself is not crashed. I have tried scrolling, zooming in, zooming out the map and its just fine. But I'm afraid at some point, this error will make a unexpected behaviour.

So, the question is : How can I solve this error ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I also am receiving this error, same situation. The error doesn't appear on non-retina devices, and on retina devices the user location pin shows as a grey square.

Comment: I got the same errors at my app. I've opened a new bug for the SDK. See here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6116

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution from the link AlexVogel provided. Just update to the latest version (v1.6.1) and I don't see this error log anymore. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

The bug AlexVogel mentions (https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6116) contains a working solution. Quoting from the answer there:

1. Drag the new GoogleMaps.framework  to the Frameworks group of your project. When prompted, select Copy items into destination group's folder.
2. Right-click GoogleMaps.framework in your project, and select Show In Finder.
3. Drag the GoogleMaps.bundle from the Resources folder to your project. We suggest putting it in the Frameworks group. When prompted, ensure Copy items into destination group's folder is not selected.

Comment: that are the standard instructions for installing it :)

Comment: I've removed the framework and re-added it and it didn't work!!